# Regex word-break with unicode diacritics

Tags: regex, unicode, word-boundary

I am working on an application that searches text using regular expressions based on input from a user. One option the user has is to include a "Match 0 or more characters" wildcard using the asterisk. I need this to only match between word boundaries. My first attempt was to convert all asterisks to `(?:(?=\B).)*`, which works fine for most cases. Where it fails is that apparently .Net considers the position between a unicode character with a diacritic and another character a word-break. I consider this a bug, and have submitted it to the [Microsoft feedback site](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=495449).

In the meantime, however, I need to get the functionality implemented and product shipped. I am considering using `[\p{L}\p{M}\p{N}\p{Pc}]*` as the replacement text, but, frankly, am in "I don't really understand what this is going to do" land. I mean, I can read the specifications, but am not confident that I could sufficiently test this to make sure it is doing what I expect. I simply wouldn't know all the boundary conditions to test. The application is used by cross-cultural workers, many of whom are in tribal locations, so any and all writing systems need to be supported, including some that use zero-width word breaks.

Does anyone have a more elegant solution, or could confirm/correct the code above, or offer some pointers?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equivalent of `/(?:(?=\B).)*/` in a unicode context would be:

```
/
(?:
  (?: (?<=[\p{L}\p{M}\p{N}\p{Pc}]) (?=[\p{L}\p{M}\p{N}\p{Pc}])
  |   (?<![\p{L}\p{M}\p{N}\p{Pc}]) (?![\p{L}\p{M}\p{N}\p{Pc}])
  )
  .
)*
/
```

...or somewhat simplified:

```
/(?:[\p{L}\p{M}\p{N}\p{Pc}]+|[^\p{L}\p{M}\p{N}\p{Pc}]+)?/
```

This would match either a word or a non-word (spacing, punctuation etc.) sequence, possibly an empty one.

A normal or negated word-boundary (`\b` or `\B`) is basically a double look-around. One looking behind, making sure of the type of character that precedes the current position. Similarly one looking ahead.

In the second regex, I removed the look-arounds and used simple character classes instead.